# Can't redirecting to another page using relative path

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redirect

I want to use JS async function redirect to another page, but it don't work.

The following is my code:

```
var myAccount = document.getElementById("account1");
var myPwd = document.getElementById("pwd");

async function validate_form(){
    this.redirectUrl = await eel.sign_in(myAccount.value, myPwd.value)();
    console.log('rendering page...，redirectUrl:'+this.redirectUrl);
    window.location.replace(this.redirectUrl);
}
```

I had try another way, but that was still fail

```
async function validate_form(){
    this.redirectUrl = await eel.sign_in(myAccount.value, myPwd.value)();
    console.log('rendering page...，redirectUrl:'+this.redirectUrl);
    try{
        await Promise.all([window.location.replace(this.redirectUrl)]) ;
    }
    catch (error){
        // Check for login session
        const response = Object.assign({}, error);
        if (response.response.status === 401 || response.response.status === 401) {
            alert(response);
        }
    }
}
```

The command `await eel.sign_in(myAccount.value, myPwd.value)()` would get value `home.html`.
Could anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What does the `eel.sign_in` function do?

Comment: Where is the `validate_form` function being called?

Comment: @Shuvo The function is about getting value from python, and I edited this again.

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo A button will trigger `validate_form` in html

Comment: @Ming, I don't understand why do you need to use `async` here?

Comment: @Shuvo I'll get some value (`hom.html`)from python, so I use `await eel.sign_in(myAccount.value, myPwd.value)();` and `async`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are specifying a relative path, You need to add `/` before the url you declared in `this.redirectUrl`.
Update your `URL` from:

```
this.redirectUrl = 'home.html';
```

to this:

```
this.redirectUrl = '/home.html';
```

Or to this:

```
this.redirectUrl = `${location.hostname}/home.html`;
```

Hopefully this should help you.